# GNU make not detecting if files are changed on windows

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I'm a noob with make in general so apologies in advance.

I have a folder structure, where foo.cpp is in the root of the project and all other .cpp files are in one and all headers in another folder. Whenever I change something make just says that everything is up to date.

Working on windows 10.

The code is from

my makefile:

```
OBJS = foo.o bar.o
CC = g++
INCLUDE_PATHS = -IC:\Mingw_libs\include\SDL2
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LC:\Mingw_libs\lib -Iheaders
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++11
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image 

OUTPUTFILE = main

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OUTPUTFILE)

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.exe

foo.o:
    $(CC) -c foo.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)

bar.o:
    $(CC) -c sources/bar.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add dependencies to your target. Make has the syntax

```
target : prerequisite
    command
```

So in your case:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

same with `bar`

the `$<` is a placeholder for the first prerequisite. So you don't have to type `foo.cpp` twice.

You can checkout more automatic variables here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

Answer (score 0):

You should declare  target dependencies like that:

```
foo.obj: foo.c
    ....
```

Otherwise make will not now wich files to check for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile has no dependencies for `foo.o` or `bar.o`.

This

```
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OUTPUTFILE)
```

says `all` depends on `$(OBJS)`.  So when one of the files in `$(OBJS)` changes, that step is run.

This says `foo.o` depends on nothing:

```
foo.o:
    $(CC) -c foo.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

You need to add the dependency:

```
foo.o: foo.cpp
    $(CC) -c foo.cpp $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

Note that the spaces after the `:` usually need to be a tab, not actual space(s).